Using different denominators in tern::count_occurrences within same split_by_row
To demostrate values using customized format "xx/xx (xx.x%)", a example is like this:
library(formatters)
library(rtables)
library(tern)

advs <- subset(ex_advs, COUNTRY %in% c("CHN", "USA"))

custom_format <- function(x, ...) {
  attr(x, "label") <- NULL
  checkmate::assert_vector(x)
  checkmate::assert_count(x["num"])
  checkmate::assert_count(x["denom"])
  result <- if (x["num"] == 0) {
    paste0(x["num"], "/", x["denom"])
  } else if (x["num"] / x["denom"] == 1){
    paste0(x["num"], "/", x["denom"]," (100)")
  }else {
    paste0(
      x["num"], "/", x["denom"],
      " (", sprintf("%.1f", round2(x["num"] / x["denom"] * 100, 1)), ")"
    )
  }
  return(result)
}

lyt <- basic_table() %>%
  rtables::split_cols_by(var = "ARM") %>%
  rtables::add_colcounts() %>%
  rtables::split_rows_by("PARAM", split_fun = drop_split_levels) %>%
  tern::count_occurrences("SITEID", .stats = "fraction",
                          .formats = list(fraction = custom_format),
                          denom = "n")

tbl <- rtables::build_table(lyt, advs)
tbl

Then you have:
> tbl
                            A: Drug X      B: Placebo    C: Combination
                             (N=588)        (N=658)         (N=567)    
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
Diastolic Blood Pressure                                               
  CHN-1                    21/84 (25.0)   20/94 (21.3)    16/81 (19.8) 
  CHN-10                       0/84        1/94 (1.1)         0/81     
  CHN-11                   12/84 (14.3)   20/94 (21.3)    16/81 (19.8) 
  CHN-12                    4/84 (4.8)     3/94 (3.2)      1/81 (1.2)  
  CHN-13                    2/84 (2.4)     6/94 (6.4)         0/81     
  CHN-14                    4/84 (4.8)     2/94 (2.1)      3/81 (3.7)  
  CHN-15                    2/84 (2.4)        0/94         4/81 (4.9)  
  CHN-16                       0/84        3/94 (3.2)      3/81 (3.7)  
  CHN-17                    4/84 (4.8)     4/94 (4.3)      3/81 (3.7)  
  CHN-18                    1/84 (1.2)        0/94         2/81 (2.5)  
  CHN-2                    9/84 (10.7)     4/94 (4.3)      3/81 (3.7)  
  CHN-3                     5/84 (6.0)     1/94 (1.1)      5/81 (6.2)  
  CHN-4                     3/84 (3.6)     3/94 (3.2)      3/81 (3.7)  
  CHN-5                     4/84 (4.8)     3/94 (3.2)      4/81 (4.9)  
  CHN-6                     1/84 (1.2)     3/94 (3.2)         0/81     
  CHN-7                        0/84        5/94 (5.3)      1/81 (1.2)  
  CHN-8                     1/84 (1.2)     1/94 (1.1)         0/81     
  CHN-9                     1/84 (1.2)     2/94 (2.1)         0/81     
  USA-1                     1/84 (1.2)     4/94 (4.3)      5/81 (6.2)  
  USA-11                    4/84 (4.8)     2/94 (2.1)      3/81 (3.7)  
  USA-12                    1/84 (1.2)     2/94 (2.1)      3/81 (3.7)  
  USA-14                    1/84 (1.2)        0/94            0/81     
  USA-15                       0/84        1/94 (1.1)      1/81 (1.2)  
  USA-17                    1/84 (1.2)     1/94 (1.1)         0/81     
  USA-19                       0/84           0/94         1/81 (1.2)  
  USA-2                        0/84           0/94         1/81 (1.2)  
  USA-3                     1/84 (1.2)        0/94         1/81 (1.2)  
  USA-4                        0/84        1/94 (1.1)      1/81 (1.2)  
  USA-5                        0/84        1/94 (1.1)         0/81     
  USA-6                        0/84        1/94 (1.1)         0/81     
  USA-8                        0/84           0/94         1/81 (1.2)  
  USA-9                     1/84 (1.2)        0/94            0/81     

It is using the value of number of uniques within this PARAM as denominator, which is 84.
If I use count_occurrences on COUNTRY:
lyt1 <- basic_table() %>%
  rtables::split_cols_by(var = "ARM") %>%
  rtables::add_colcounts() %>%
  rtables::split_rows_by("PARAM", split_fun = drop_split_levels) %>%
  tern::count_occurrences("COUNTRY")

tbl1 <- rtables::build_table(lyt1, advs)
tbl1

Then you have this:
> tbl1
                           A: Drug X    B: Placebo   C: Combination
                            (N=588)      (N=658)        (N=567)    
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
Diastolic Blood Pressure                                           
  CHN                      74 (12.6%)   81 (12.3%)     64 (11.3%)  
  USA                      10 (1.7%)    13 (2.0%)      17 (3.0%)   

What I want is to use the value of a COUNTRY as the demoninator for all associated SITEID in tbl, for example, I want 74 (see from tbl1) to be the denominator for all SITEID started with CHN-, because all those sites are in COUNTRY == "CHN", rather than 84, likewise, 10 for those SITEID in COUNTRY == "USA", rather than 84.
Is that what current ratbles and tern can do? Thanks for your thoughts in advance!
